# How can I get ID of div created in loop using onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a color selector and I have this code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
for (var i=0; i<256; i++)
{
  document.write("<div id="+i+" style='display:inline;background-color: rgb("+i+",0,0);'>&nbsp;</div>")
}
function movercolor()
{
  document.getElementById('rmover').innerHTML = ("<div style='background-color: rgb("+i+",0,0);'>&nbsp;</div>");
}
//-->
</script>
```

I am trying to make it so that the function movercolor() displays what ever color it is hovering over in my color bar.  As of now it just displays the same color no matter where I hover over the 256 divs which is max red.  How can I make it so that the color changes as I move my mouse over different divs?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using CSS classes as far as I can, and you will—IMHO—get better control over where to place dynamically created elements if you append them.

[edit] You need to send in a parameter to the function `movercolor`, but you can achieve that without using the element's id.

```js
var colorSpaceElement = document.getElementById("color-space");

for (var i=0; i<256; i++) {
  colorSpaceElement.append( createColorElement(i) );
}

function createColorElement(redIndex) {
  var divElement = document.createElement("div");
  
  divElement.style = "background-color: rgb("+redIndex+",0,0)";
  divElement.classList.add("color");
  divElement.onmouseover = function() { movercolor(redIndex); };
  
  return divElement;
}

function movercolor(redIndex) {
  document.getElementById('rmover').style = "background-color: rgb("+redIndex+",0,0);";
}
```

```css
#rmover {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 256);  
  height: 30px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div id="color-space"></div>

<div id="rmover">rmover</div>
```

Comment: You should explain how your answer does what he wants. The code provided in the question would have just set the `div` to the last color.

Comment: I reused his code and expanded upon it. What else is that to explain?